# displaying hex sent from socket connection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

im using [LXsocket](http://code.google.com/p/entropydb/wiki/SocketWrapper) as my networking provider 
i have setup a server and client for testing.  i also have wireshark in place to see whats being sent
client:

```
    socket = [[LXSocket alloc] init];
        if ([socket connect: host port: port] == NO) 
        { 
            //cant connect!
            [socket release]; 
            NSLog(@"cannot create socket"); 
            return FALSE;
        }

        //connect hex string being sent
        const char connectByteArray[] = {
            0x01, 0x00, 0x07, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x40
        };

//send bytes    this works and the packets shown in wireshark reflect the byte array above
        [socket sendBytes:connectByteArray length:sizeof(connectByteArray)];

//receive bytes
        id *object = [socket readBytesWithLength:sizeof(connectByteArray)];
```

Server:

```
LXSocket* serverSocket = [[LXSocket alloc] init];
    [serverSocket bindToPort: 1234];
    [serverSocket listen: 5];
    LXSocket *socket = [serverSocket accept];


    const char connectByteArray[] = {
        0x01, 0x00, 0x07, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x40
    };


    [socket sendBytes:connectByteArray length:sizeof(connectByteArray)];
```

my problem is that i cannot get cocoa to export the byte array properly.  i have tried many different format tags without any luck.  how can i get this to log the proper byte array, ie.         01:00:07:7f:00:00:01:00:03:40   ????

```
NSLog(@"return data %X",object);
     NSLog(@"return data %f",object);
     NSLog(@"return data %e",object);
     NSLog(@"return data %llu",object);
     NSLog(@"return data %hu",object);
```

2011-08-24 08:24:44.507 Chameleon[5574:207] return data 4C053B0

2011-08-24 08:24:44.508 Chameleon[5574:207] return data 0.000000

2011-08-24 08:24:44.509 Chameleon[5574:207] return data 2.125934e-313

2011-08-24 08:24:44.510 Chameleon[5574:207] return data 43029386160

2011-08-24 08:24:44.511 Chameleon[5574:207] return data 21424

```
#import "LXSocket.h"
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <sys/types.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
#import <netdb.h>

@implementation LXSocket

+ (id)socket {
    return [[[LXSocket alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (id)initWithCSocket:(SOCKET)_socket {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        m_socket = _socket;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)bindToPort:(unsigned)port {
    struct sockaddr_in service;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    service.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (bind(m_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &service, sizeof(service)) == -1) {
        NSLog(@"bind() failed -- %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(m_socket);
        return NO;
    } else return YES;
}

- (BOOL)listen:(unsigned)limit {
    if (listen(m_socket, limit) == -1) {
        printf("listen(): Error listening on socket\n");
        return NO;
    } else return YES;
}

- (LXSocket*)accept {
    SOCKET AcceptSocket;
    while (YES) {
        AcceptSocket = -1;
        while (AcceptSocket == -1) {
            AcceptSocket = accept(m_socket, NULL, NULL);
        }
        //printf("Server: Client Connected!\n");
        //m_socket = AcceptSocket; 
        return [[LXSocket alloc] initWithCSocket: AcceptSocket];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)connect:(NSString*)host port:(unsigned)port {
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([host UTF8String]);
    clientService.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (connect(m_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &clientService, sizeof(clientService)) == -1) {
        printf("Client: connect() - Failed to connect.\n");
        return NO;
    } else return YES;
}

- (BOOL)sendBytes:(const void*)bytes length:(unsigned)len {
    int sent = send(m_socket, bytes, len, 0);
    return sent == len;
}

- (void*)readBytesWithLength:(unsigned)len {
    void* buffer = malloc(len);
    int received = recv(m_socket, buffer, len, 0);
    if (received <= 0) {
        free(buffer);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (received < len) {
        unsigned remaining = len;
        char* ptr = buffer;
        do {
            remaining -= received;
            ptr += received;
            received = recv(m_socket, ptr, remaining, 0);
            if (received <= 0) {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            }
        } while (received < remaining);
    }
    return buffer;
}

- (BOOL)sendData:(NSData*)data {
    const void* ptr = [data bytes];
    BOOL succeeded = NO;
    if ([self sendInt: [data length]])
        if ([self sendBytes: ptr length: [data length]]) succeeded = YES;
    //free(ptr);
    return succeeded;
}

- (NSData*)readData{
    unsigned len = [self readInt];
    if (len > 0) {
        void* ptr = [self readBytesWithLength: len];
        if (ptr != NULL) {
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes: ptr length: len];
            free(ptr);
            return data;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)sendObject:(id)object {
    NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData: data];
    [archiver encodeRootObject: object];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    BOOL succeeded = [self sendData: data];
    [archiver release];
    [data release];
    return succeeded;
}

- (id)readObject {
    NSData* data = [self readData];
    if (data != nil) {
        NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData: data];
        id object = [[[unarchiver decodeObject] retain] autorelease];
        [unarchiver release];
        return object;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)sendInt:(int)n {
    return [self sendBytes: &n length: sizeof(n)];
}

- (BOOL)sendDouble:(double)n {
    return [self sendBytes: &n length: sizeof(n)];
}

- (BOOL)sendInt64:(long long)n {
    return [self sendBytes: &n length: sizeof(n)];
}

- (int)readInt {
    void* buffer = [self readBytesWithLength: sizeof(int)];
    if (buffer == NULL) return 0;
    int n;
    memcpy(&n, buffer, sizeof(n));
    free(buffer);
    return n;
}

- (double)readDouble {
    void* buffer = [self readBytesWithLength: sizeof(double)];
    if (buffer == NULL) return 0;
    double n;
    memcpy(&n, buffer, sizeof(n));
    free(buffer);
    return n;
}

- (long long)readInt64 {
    void* buffer = [self readBytesWithLength: sizeof(long long)];
    if (buffer == NULL) return 0;
    long long n;
    memcpy(&n, buffer, sizeof(n));
    free(buffer);
    return n;
}

- (BOOL)sendShort:(short)n {
    return [self sendBytes: &n length: sizeof(n)];
}

- (short)readShort {
    void* buffer = [self readBytesWithLength: sizeof(short)];
    if (buffer == NULL) return 0;
    short n;
    memcpy(&n, buffer, sizeof(n));
    free(buffer);
    return n;
}

- (BOOL)sendLong:(long)n {
    return [self sendBytes: &n length: sizeof(n)];
}

- (BOOL)sendUnsingedLongLong:(unsigned long long)n {
    return YES;//return [self sendBytes: &n length: sizeof(n)];
}

- (long)readLong {
    void* buffer = [self readBytesWithLength: sizeof(long)];
    if (buffer == NULL) return 0;
    long n;
    memcpy(&n, buffer, sizeof(n));
    free(buffer);
    return n;
}

- (void)sendString:(NSString*)string {
    const char* s = [string UTF8String];
    int len = strlen(s);
    [self sendInt: len];
    [self sendBytes: s length: len + 1];
}

- (NSString*)readString {
    int len = [self readInt];
    char* s = [self readBytesWithLength: len + 1];
    NSString* string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: s];
    free(s);
    return string;
}

- (NSString*)resolveHostName:(NSString*)hostName {
    struct hostent* host = gethostbyname([hostName UTF8String]);
    if (host == NULL) {
        printf("Error resolving host name: %d\n", strerror(errno));
        return nil;
    } else {
        struct in_addr* addr = (struct in_addr*) host->h_addr_list[0];
        char* ip = inet_ntoa(*addr);
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String: ip];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    close(m_socket);
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Some further results (remember original hex string being passed is        0x01, 0x00, 0x07, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x40)(0100077f000001000340):

```
   id *object = [socket readBytesWithLength:10];
    NSLog(@"return data %X",*object);   =  return data 7F070001
   NSLog(@"return data %llu",*object);  =  return data 45080838145


   double object = [socket readInt64];
    NSLog(@"return data %X",*object);   =  return data F0700010
    NSLog(@"return data %llu",*object); = return data 4823355235012444176 (hex: 0x42F00007F0700010)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to write a special function to print in this way because you need to loop through the characters:

```
- (NSString *)bytesToString:(char *)bytes length:(int)length {
    // Each byte is 2 hex characters, plus we need a ':' between each byte
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:2*length + length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i < length - 1) {
            [result appendFormat:@"%02X:", bytes[i]];
        }
        else {
            [result appendFormat:@"%02X", bytes[i]];
        }
    }

    return result; // Result is auto-released
}
```

With this function defined, you should be able to log as follows:

```
NSLog(@"return data %@",[self bytesToString:object length:sizeof(connectByteArray)]);
```

Comment: thank your very much for the response.  the only thing is that in the NSLOG statement you use the same array created for the send.  it should look like this:    id *object = [socket readBytesWithLength:sizeof(connectByteArray1)];
    NSLog(@"return data %@",[self bytesToString:object]);
but even this logs  return data 7F070001:10000:4003:00

Comment: i will continue to play with this though

Comment: Something is strange with the way readBytesWithLength returns its results. You have the return type defined as id *, but that doesn't make much sense for something that returns an array bytes. If it returned an Objective-C object I would expect the return type to be just id. If it were bytes I would expect it to be char * or some variant of that. I can't fine documentation for this method online. Can you post the relevant declaration of this method from the include file you're using?

Comment: its the first link (LXSocket)  or u can google LXSocket and the top link will be their github (it reads socketwrapper)

Comment: added it to the main question

Comment: It seems like somewhere between reading the bytes from the socket and printing them, something is converting the bytes into a 4-byte integer. So "01:00:07:7f"gets converted to "7f070001", etc. I'm not sure where that can be happening. I tried to reproduce on my own machine using the straight const char array rather than a socket to the server, and it prints correctly no matter what I do. I've removed the unnecessary unsigned long casts from my answer, but I don't think those would have caused the problem you're seeing. If it still doesn't work I recommend stepping through with the debugger

Comment: got it working, sort of.  i only get 8bytes from the socket read method.  but i need 10bytes back?  any ideas why i would only get the 8 instead of the whole 10?

Comment: Where is it getting set to 8? Have you verified that is showing a size of 10 bytes on the sending side?

Comment: tried to add my findings here but it looked ugly.  see at the bottom of the original question.  section: "Some further results"

Comment: You are now declaring the return type as id *, and then dereferencing it in your NSLog. It's not an id * that is returned, it is a void * that happens to point to a char buffer. Instead of trying to print any of these values in NSLog, try calling the function I supplied in my original answer and printing the NSString that is returned. Your code that calls readInt64 will always return 8 bytes because that's how big a long long is.

Comment: that returns: 7F070001:10000:A34003:00    (4 bytes of the string)i could be wrong but it looks like its reading pass the buffer so everything pass the 7f700001 isnt real return data

Comment: ok check this out: when i specify 10 for len i get : return data 7F070001:10000:4003:00:4E24EF0:00:0C:4DD620:0D:02   which seems to have my whole string.  but its quite construded

Comment: I'm not sure how this output is possible if you've implemented the function I posted to print. My function is placing the ":" between every element in a char array and this one is including a full 4 bytes. Double-check to make sure you've removed your use of "id *" as the return type of the readWithBytes function, and also make sure the "bytes" parameter of bytesToString is declared as a char *. If your code is now different than one you have posted, please update your post.

Comment: @owengerig let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2978/discussion-between-tim-dean-and-owen-gerig)

Comment: sorry i did add the id*.  not sure what i was thinking at the time.  once i put char * back in there everything worked and is properly displayed.  its kinda cool though, i see now it that it was determining the size of each element by that type/size and thats why it was off. anyways thank you very much